# How to set value to JSON to based on @value

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, parameters, json.net

I received this format of JSON string from some API.

```
{
   "onlineRequest":{  
      "MobileNumber":"75484568",
      "ProductNo":"100",
      "JsonFile":{
        "dropdown":[  
        {  
          "@para-id":"2572",
          "@new-code":"",
          "@text":"This is first dropdown",
          "option":[  
             {  
                "@text":"Option 1",
                "@value":"0"
             }
          ]
        },
        {  
          "@para-id":"2584",
          "@new-code":"",
          "@text":"This is second dropdown",
          "option":[  
             {  
                "@text":"Excellent",
                "@value":"2"
             }
          ]
        },
        {  
          "@para-id":"2575",
          "@new-code":"",
          "@text":"This is third dropdown",
          "option":[  
             {  
                "@text":"Not Available",
                "@value":"1"
             }
          ]
        }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

In order to this JSON string, I need to bind the values to
JSON. each parameter ID has separate @value. which is dynamical. value of the `@value` can be 0,1,2,3,4

> When @para-id = 2572,
>
> if @value = 0, I need to pass the value to @new-code = 50,
>
> if @value = 1, I need to pass the value to @new-code = 60,
>
> if @value = 2, I need to pass the value to @new-code = 70
>
> When @para-id = 2584,
>
> if @value = 0, I need to pass the value to @new-code = 10,
>
> if @value = 1, I need to pass the value to @new-code = 20,
>
> if @value = 2, I need to pass the value to @new-code = 30,
>
> When @para-id = 2575,
>
> if @value = 0, I need to pass the value to @new-code = "A",
>
> if @value = 1, I need to pass the value to @new-code = "B"

**Expected Output :**

```
"dropdown":[  
   {  
      "@para-id":"2572",
      "@new-code":"50",
      "@text":"This is first dropdown",
      "option":[  
         {  
            "@text":"Option 1",
            "@value":"0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "@para-id":"2584",
      "@new-code":"30",
      "@text":"This is second dropdown",
      "option":[  
         {  
            "@text":"Excellent",
            "@value":"2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "@para-id":"2575",
      "@new-code":"B",
      "@text":"This is third dropdown",
      "option":[  
         {  
            "@text":"Not Available",
            "@value":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How can I do this using C#. please help me to solve this.

**Updated:**

in order to JSON, I created a model class. but the problem is when using @text,@value and @para-id.I know I can't create fields like this

```
public class Option
{
    public string @text { get; set; }
    public string @value { get; set; }
}

public class Dropdown
{
    public string @para-id { get; set; }
    public string @new-code { get; set; }
    public string @text { get; set; }
    public List<Option> option { get; set; }
}

public class JsonFile
{
    public List<Dropdown> dropdown { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineRequest
{
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductNo { get; set; }
    public JsonFile JsonFile { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public OnlineRequest onlineRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create a model as per your api json and convert json object to your model type then you can foreach in dropdown and conditionally set new code

Comment: @HiteshKansagara can you please help me to do that, I have no idea to do it. please sir

Comment: @HiteshKansagara I added a model class. Is this correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize that JSON using this... It will first deserialize, project the `Dropdown` element and reserialize it to the JSON format

```
void Main()
{
    string testJson = @"{""onlineRequest"":{""MobileNumber"":""75484568"",""ProductNo"":""100"",""JsonFile"":{""dropdown"":[{""@para-id"":""2572"",""@new-code"":"""",""@text"":""This is first dropdown"",""option"":[{""@text"":""Option 1"",""@value"":""0""}]},{""@para-id"":""2584"",""@new-code"":"""",""@text"":""This is second dropdown"",""option"":[{""@text"":""Excellent"",""@value"":""2""}]},{""@para-id"":""2575"",""@new-code"":"""",""@text"":""This is third dropdown"",""option"":[{""@text"":""Not Available"",""@value"":""1""}]}]}}}";

    Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(testJson);

    var dropdowns = response.OnlineRequest.JsonFile;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dropdowns, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}


public class Option
{

    [JsonProperty("@text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Dropdown
{

    [JsonProperty("@para-id")]
    public string ParaId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@new-code")]
    public string NewCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("option")]
    public IList<Option> Option { get; set; }
}

public class JsonFile
{

    [JsonProperty("dropdown")]
    public IList<Dropdown> Dropdown { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineRequest
{

    [JsonProperty("MobileNumber")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProductNo")]
    public string ProductNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("JsonFile")]
    public JsonFile JsonFile { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{

    [JsonProperty("onlineRequest")]
    public OnlineRequest OnlineRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Output looks like this

```
{
  "dropdown": [
    {
      "@para-id": "2572",
      "@new-code": "",
      "@text": "This is first dropdown",
      "option": [
        {
          "@text": "Option 1",
          "@value": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@para-id": "2584",
      "@new-code": "",
      "@text": "This is second dropdown",
      "option": [
        {
          "@text": "Excellent",
          "@value": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@para-id": "2575",
      "@new-code": "",
      "@text": "This is third dropdown",
      "option": [
        {
          "@text": "Not Available",
          "@value": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: in response to comment, change the NewCode property to this

```
void Main()
{
    string testJson = @"{""onlineRequest"":{""MobileNumber"":""75484568"",""ProductNo"":""100"",""JsonFile"":{""dropdown"":[{""@para-id"":""2572"",""@new-code"":"""",""@text"":""This is first dropdown"",""option"":[{""@text"":""Option 1"",""@value"":""0""}]},{""@para-id"":""2584"",""@new-code"":"""",""@text"":""This is second dropdown"",""option"":[{""@text"":""Excellent"",""@value"":""2""}]},{""@para-id"":""2575"",""@new-code"":"""",""@text"":""This is third dropdown"",""option"":[{""@text"":""Not Available"",""@value"":""1""}]}]}}}";

    Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(testJson);

    var dropdowns = response.OnlineRequest.JsonFile;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dropdowns, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}


public class Option
{

    [JsonProperty("@text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Dropdown
{

    [JsonProperty("@para-id")]
    public string ParaId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@new-code")]
    public string NewCode {
        get{
            if (this.Option.Count == 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return this.Option.First().Value;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("@text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("option")]
    public IList<Option> Option { get; set; }
}

public class JsonFile
{

    [JsonProperty("dropdown")]
    public IList<Dropdown> Dropdown { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineRequest
{

    [JsonProperty("MobileNumber")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ProductNo")]
    public string ProductNo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("JsonFile")]
    public JsonFile JsonFile { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{

    [JsonProperty("onlineRequest")]
    public OnlineRequest OnlineRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wooow awesome sir :) you save part of my life. can you please tell me how can I set values to `@new-code` based on `@value` please give me a sample code sir.please

Comment: @Gamma updated the solution, would appreciate a vote up and a selected answer. good luck

Comment: Thanks in advance for your kindly response sir. I'm new to the C# so. I don't have an idea to do that. In that json, there have multiple  `@para-id`..like 2575,2584. so ,then I need to check `@value` for each `@para-id`. so then I have to set `@new-code` based on @value. I'm stack on there now. How to do that

Comment: No sir!! :( but I accepted answer because of your kindly response :) If you can please help me to solve this

Comment: ok just copy paste the last part n that case and it will work

Comment: The model class now ok sir, I ask now how to get I **Expected JSON Output:** now?  how to check `@para-id` and there `@value`? then how I set `@new-code` based on `@value` ?

Comment: My main question is how to set values to `@new-code` based on each `@value` .